# Bootstrap 3 Footer issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a footer which will stick to the bottom of the browser if there's not enough content, or stick to the bottom of the page if there is enough content such that it exceeds the browser's height. Does there exist a

```
.navbar-static-bottom
```

class in bootstrap3?

On a separate note, I'm having some issues with styling my footer. I would like links to the left, and some plain text to the right. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rxnS/26/) is the opposite of what I want. I don't think that pull-right and pull-left is the ideal solution. It seems kinda hacky. I changed button to pull-left and the text to pull right, which only gave the (almost) right look when the window was condensed.[image: ideal] The margins are off though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplish this using a bit a JavaScript:

```
$(window).bind('load', function () {

    resizeElements();

    function resizeElements() {

        headerHeight = $('.navbar').height();
        footerHeight = $('footer').height();

        if (($(document.body).height() + footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
            $footer.addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
        } else {
            $footer.removeClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(resizeElements);

});
```

This allows me to avoid any wrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can to use **.navbar-fixed-bottom** class to if you want the footer to be fixed at bottom.

In case you need a sticky footer you can try this

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="main" class="container clear-top">
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="footer" style="background-color:#c2c2c2">
 </footer>

CSS:
html,body
{
height:100%;
}

#wrap
{
min-height: 100%;
}

 #main
 {
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom:150px; /* this needs to be bigger than footer height*/
}

footer { position: relative; margin-top: -150px; /* negative value
of footer height */ height: 150px; clear:both; padding-top:20px;
color:#fff; }
```

Found this here http://bootstrapfooter.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2rxnS/27/ In that link, the bottom text is cut off. I want to have the footer visible only if the user has scrolled down to the bottom of the page or there's not enough content to fill up the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code works for me:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="footer"> 
    <footer> 
           <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                      &copy; 2013 

                                      <br>
                                      Powered by 
                                      <a href="http://getbootstrap.com title="Bootstrap">Bootsrap</a>
                                      &middot;
                                     <a href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/" title="Fontawesome">Fontawesome</a>
                       </div>   
        </div>
      </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #footer{
        position:relative;
        bottom:0;
        background-color:@navbar-inverse-bg;
        border-color:@navbar-inverse-border;

    color:@navbar-inverse-color;
}
```